# Use Reactive-Streams Processor with RxJava 2.0

Tags: rx-java, reactive-streams, rx-java2

I have an `org.reactivestreams.Processor` that I would like use with RxJava 2.0. However, while there are conversions to integrate an`org.reactivestreams.Publisher` with RxJava, like `io.reactivex.Flowable#fromPublisher`, it is not clear to me how to best integrate a `org.reactivestreams.Processor` (or `org.reactivestreams.Subscriber`). Can anyone shine some light on this?

Answer (score 0):

You wrap the `Publisher` side and keep the `Subscriber` side as is:

```
Processor proc = ...

Subscriber sub = proc;
Flowable flow = Flowable.fromPublisher(proc);

flow.map(v -> v.toString()).subscribe(System.out::println);

sub.onNext(1);
```

Comment: Hmm, but then I might violate the reactive streams contract, that specifies that `onNext` must not be called more often then requested via `Subscription#request(long)`.

Comment: It depends on where you got that processor or if it coordinates downstream requests or not. RxJava's processors don't coordinate and they would always request Long.MAX_VALUE if you send them a Subscription.

Comment: The processor confirms to the [spec](https://github.com/reactive-streams/reactive-streams-jvm/blob/v1.0.0/README.md#specification) and has been successfully integrated with akka streams. I thought that unlike RxJava 1.x, RxJava 2.0 supports back pressure...

Comment: Given my example, you are still driving the Akka Processor via sub so you have to get the request amount out of the Processor yourself. The flowable wrapper will dutifully relay the requests of a Flowable-based chain to the Publisher side of the Processor.